# Is this raw SQL statement safe from SQL Injection?

Tags: laravel

This is my first time using a raw sql statement in laravel, so I wanted to make sure this was the best way to use it.

```sql
$events = DB::select("
SELECT
    *
FROM
    events
WHERE
    (
        start_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date OR
        end_date BETWEEN :start_date AND :end_date OR
        :start_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date OR
        :end_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
    )
AND agenda_id = :agenda_id",
[
    'start_date' => Carbon::parse($dataEvent['start_date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'end_date' => Carbon::parse($dataEvent['end_date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'agenda_id' => $dataEvent['agenda_id'],
]);
```

Comment: Yes, because you use bounded placeholders and no raw variables in the query itself. However, use models and eloquent if you're using Laravel.

Comment: It is safe for injection but lead to SQL error date values cannot be parsed. So better to put some validation code before putting those values into parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provide defense against SQL injection. this is because since the query builder is using PDO in the background, we know there is a way to bind parameters to our query so it will sanitize the bound variables. Here you will know how Laravel prevent SQL injection with **[Raw SQL  Queries](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries)**

The SQL injection risk comes mainly and usually if there is data sent through **GET** or **POST** request. You should protect your database from SQL injections by binding data to the raw query as :

```
$data = $request->name; // this comes from an input field
$query = DB::select(
    DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name=:user_name ")
    ,['user_name' => $data] // binds data with array
    )
;
```

Please notice the colon **":"** and variable next to it. This will protect your query from SQL injections.